# Retrieving Parse ObjectID in OnTimeClickListener method

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-listview

I want to retrieve an objectID of an item (to be specific, it's a class called "Room" in our Parse Model) clicked within a `ListView`.
And after that, I want to pass the retrieved ObjectID to another class using `Intent`.

I tried parse docs' getObjectId(); method but seems like it won't work.
How should I retrieve it?

Here's my code.

```
Button createBtn;
Button searchBtn;
Button myGroupBtn;
Button settingBtn;


String[] courses;
List<String> listItems;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView listView;
TextView textView;
// when CREAT button is tapped
public void createBtn(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Create.class);
    // Removes animation
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(i);
}
// when Setting button is tapped
public void settingBtn(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Setting.class);
    // Removes animation
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(i);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String courseName = intent.getStringExtra("courseName");
    String courseNumber = intent.getStringExtra("courseNumber");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
    // Making Links to Buttons on Create
    createBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createBtn);
    searchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
    myGroupBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myGroupBtn);
    settingBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingBtn);


    //Chaning the button colors
    searchBtn.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    createBtn.setTextColor(0xFFBFBFBF);
    myGroupBtn.setTextColor(0xFFBFBFBF);
    settingBtn.setTextColor(0xFFBFBFBF);

    listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(courseName + " " + courseNumber);

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> roomQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Room");
    roomQuery.whereEqualTo("course" , courseName);
    roomQuery.whereEqualTo("number" , courseNumber);

    roomQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject room : objects) {

                    Log.i("Appinfo", String.valueOf(room.get("title")));
                    String stringToAdd = "";

                    String opened = String.valueOf(room.get("opened"));
                    String x;
                    if(opened.equals(true)){
                        x = "Open";
                    }else{
                        x = "Closed";
                    }

                    stringToAdd = stringToAdd + String.valueOf(room.get("studyDate")) + "   " +
                            String.valueOf(room.get("category")) + "    " + x + "\n"
                            + String.valueOf(room.get("title")) +
                            "            "
                    ;
                    listItems.add(stringToAdd);
                    Log.i("Appinfo", "A");
                }


            } else {
                Log.i("Appinfo", "B");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    initList();

}
public void initList() {

    Log.i("Appinfo", "C");



    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_two, R.id.txtvw, listItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Room.class);
    String category = listItems.get(position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you loose the `objectId` of Parse in your "`Adapter`": you use `Strings` and the basic android `Adapter` (there: `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_two, R.id.txtvw, listItems);`) to display your elements; the problem is that converting your complicated Room object into `String` which does not contain a lot of informations makes you loose the `objectId` you want to keep.

The solution to your problem is a very Android-ish pattern called `Adapter` or more specifically for this case a `Custom Adapter` which will explain to the device how to render your `Room` elements into every cell of your app's `ListView`.

It is extremely well documented (much better that everything I could possibility write in this post) so [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) is the generic official doc and here is, to me, [the best tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) to get the concept.

PS: for a beginner, I recommend the [Base Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), it is, to me, the simplest :)